# Can we access environment variables in ECS task definition via a react application hosted in ECS Fargate?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, environment-variables, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a react application hosted in ECS Fargate and I have defined some environment variables in the task definition. Can I access those environment variables using the react frontend?

`console.log(process.env);` does not return any environment variables in the ecs task definition.

Comment: React apps run in the user's web browser, not the server. The server just serves up the raw JavaScript files to the web browser. So no, the server's environment variables are not available inside the React code.